# Can you tell whether I have a hardware or software problem with a DVD-ROM drive?

Tags: dvd, cd, cd-drive, drive

Trying to copy the content of a DVD on a Asrock ION 330 running Maverick, i.e. with:

`dd if=/dev/sr0 of=dvdcopy`

...I get errors in /var/log/messages:

`Jan 15 17:18:15 asrock kernel: [ 2616.445966] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Unhandled sense code

Jan 15 17:18:15 asrock kernel: [ 2616.445975] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE

Jan 15 17:18:15 asrock kernel: [ 2616.445984] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 

Jan 15 17:18:15 asrock kernel: [ 2616.445994] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Id CRC or ECC error

Jan 15 17:18:15 asrock kernel: [ 2616.446004] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00`

I'd tell it is a hardware problem, but it happens with various DVDs and on a second PC, also running Maverick... Both the PCs previously ran Lucid, same problems.

Edit: the DVD-ROMs are proven working on my brother's PC.

Edit #2: I'd like also hints about what to look for on Google.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is an encryption problem.
You may need [libdvdcss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libdvdcss)

Search for it synaptic or

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdcss-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy a DVD use brasero. Save the dvd as an iso.

Comment: Thank you Roland for your answer. I tried. The generated iso size is 2 kB (but the real size is 4GB!). Brasero terminates with no errors telling me the size is 368,8 MB (also wrong).

Comment: ahh well probably you are trying to copy protected DVDs? I highly doubt you would have the same problem on two systems with the same DVDs and it be a software/hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks again Roland: no, they're not protected DVD; the problems happens also with DVD-ROMs...

Comment: No clue then, seems like a problem with the DVDs to me. Is this a fresh install of 10.10?

Comment: no,it isn't. It is an upgrade from 10.04

Comment: kk I'll leave this one to a kernel expert then - must be a common factor in terms of the configurations you used on your systems.

Answer (score 1):

You do not give any clue what hardware you have. I had that problem (and suspend/hibernate issue) on an old Dell Inspiron 8200 laptop. It had a hot swap drive bay that had a DVD drive in it. But apparently because it could be hot swapped, Linux kept polling for a floppy drive, resulting in log errors attempting to read `fd0`, lack of auto mounting USB or CD/DVD's, and failed to suspend or hibernate because it could not put udisks-deamon to sleep, which kept polling for the non-existing floppy.

So if you have no floppy and are getting any `fd0` errors in `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages` similar to "end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0", either disable the floppy in your BIOS, or if that does not work:

Add following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (use sudo or gksu to run your editor):

```
# In /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist floppy
```

Then do: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Then reboot and see if USB and other removable media auto mounts when inserted.

Note that other partitions on internal drives are not auto mounted unless you make proper mount points (usually in /media unless you want it mounted elsewhere) and entries in `/etc/fstab` (preferably using UUID). Although, they will mount if you have permission and select them in Places.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I´d try it´s to update your DVD-ROM firmware -for compatibility with more media types- going to the manufacturer support page, next thing i´d try changing the burning software to another one: K3B, Brasero or DVDTools for example. If nothing of this works maybe it´s a problem with your mainboard controller try to change the connector to another if it´s a SATA DVD-ROM -if it´s ATA not, and finally try to update your kernel to a newer one, you can do it without the need of knowing complex commands, see intructions here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/how-to-compile-kernel-in-ubuntu-easy.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is in your case, but hopefully my results  can give you some insight. This is the output I get from a CD that has known damaged/scratched sectors (starting at sector 944128)

```
sr 5:0:1:0: [sr1]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 5:0:1:0: [sr1]  Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 5:0:1:0: [sr1]  Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
sr 5:0:1:0: [sr1] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 03 9a 00 00 00 40 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 944128
Buffer I/O error on device sr1, logical block 118016
Buffer I/O error on device sr1, logical block 118017
Buffer I/O error on device sr1, logical block 118018
Buffer I/O error on device sr1, logical block 118019
```